# How to configure babel-node --preset env without .babelrc

Tags: node.js, babeljs

How do you pass options to the env preset when using babel-node through the command line? I've looked through [the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node) but was unable to find how to configure the babel-node env preset.

What I'm trying to target the current version of node installed on my machine. The equivalent with a `.babelrc` file would be

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline --presets flag.

For Example:

```
  babel-node index.js --presets=env
```

Comment: and how do you configure the env preset?